# Good resources for extreme minified JavaScript (js1k-style)

Tags: javascript, minify, js1k

As I'm sure most of the JavaScripters out there are aware, there's a new, [Christmas-themed js1k](http://js1k.com/2010-xmas/). I'm planning on entering this time, but I have no experience producing such minified code. Does anyone know any good resources for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 14):

[Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) is a good javascript minifier.

There is a good [online tool](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) for quick use, or you can download the tool and run it as part of a web site build process.

---

**Edit:** Added a non-exhaustive list of tricks that you can use to minify JavaScript extremely, before using a minifier:

**Shorten long variable names**
Use shortened references to built in variables like `d=document;w=window`.

**Set Interval**
The `setInterval` function can take either a function or a string. Pass in a string to reduce the number of characters used: `setInterval('a--;b++',10)`. *Note* that passing in a string forces an eval invokation so it will be slower than passing in a function.

**Reduce Mathematical Calculations**
Example `a=b+b+b` can be reduced to `a=3*b`.

**Use Scientific Notation**
`10000` can be expressed in scientific notation as `1E4` saving 2 bytes.

**Drop leading Zeroes**
`0.2 = .2` saves a byte

**Ternery Operator**

```
if (a > b) {
     result = x;
}
else {
  result = y;
}
```

can be expressed as `result=a>b?x:y`

**Drop Braces**
Braces are only required for blocks of more than one statement.

**Operator Precedence**
Rely on operator precedence rather than adding unneeded brackets which aid code readability.

**Shorten Variable Assignment**
Rather than `function x(){a=1,b=2;...}()` pass values into the function, `function x(a,b){...}(1,2)`

**Think outside the box**
Don't automatically reach for standard ways of doing things. Rather than using `d.getElementById('p')` to get a reference to a DOM element, could you use `b.children[4]` where `d=document;b=body`.

---

Original source for above list of tricks:

http://thingsinjars.com/post/293/the-quest-for-extreme-javascript-minification/

Answer (score 4):

Spolto is right.
Any code minifier won't do the trick alone. You need to first optimize your code and then make some dirty manual tweaks.

In addition to Spolto's list of tricks I want to encourage the use of **logical operators** instead of the classical `if` `else` syntax. ex:
The following code

```
if(condition){
    exp1;
}else{
    exp2;
}
```

is somewhat equivalent to

```
condition&&exp1||exp2;
```

Another thing to consider might be *multiple variable declaration* :

```
var a = 1;var b = 2;var c = 1;
```

can be rewritten as :

```
var a=c=1,b=2;
```

Spolto is also right about the braces. You should drop them. But in addition, you should know that they can be dropped even for blocks of more expressions by writing the expressions delimited by a comma(with a leading **;** of course) :

```
if(condition){
    exp1;
    exp2;
    exp3;
}else{
    exp4;
    exp5;
}
```

Can be rewritten as :

```
 if(condition)exp1,exp2,exp3;
 else exp4,exp5;
```

Although it's not much (it saves you only 1 character/block for those who are counting), it might come in handy. (By the way, the latest *Google Closure Compiler* does this trick too).

Another trick worth mentioning is the controversial `with` functionality.
If you care more about the size, then you should use this because it might reduce code size.
For example, let's consider this object method:

```
object.method=function(){
    this.a=this.b;
    this.c++;
    this.d(this.e);
}
```

This can be rewritten as :

```
object.method=function(){
    with(this){
        a=b;
        c++;
        d(e);
    }
}
```

which is in most cases signifficantly smaller.

Something that most code packers & minifiers do not do is replacing large repeating tokens in the code with smaller ones. This is a nasty hack that also requires the use of `eval`, but since we're in it for the space, I don't think that should be a problem. Let's say you have this code :

```
a=function(){/*code here*/}; 
b=function(){/*code here*/};
c=function(){/*code here*/};
/*...*/
z=function(){/*code here*/};
```

This code has many *"function"* keywords repeating. What if you could replace them with a single(unused) character and then evaluate the code?
Here's how I would do it :

```
eval('a=F(){/*codehere*/};b=F(){/*codehere*/};c=F(){/*codehere*/};/*...*/z=F(){/*codehere*/};'.replace(/function/g,'F'));
```

Of course the replaced token(s) can be anything since our code is reduced to an evaluated string (ex: we could've replaced *=function(){* with *F*, thus saving even more characters).
Note that this technique must be used with caution, because you can easily screw up your code with multiple text replacements; moreover, you should use it only in cases where it helps (ex: if you only have **4 *function*** tokens, replacing them with a smaller token and then evaluating the code might actually increase the code length :

```
var a = "eval(''.replace(/function/g,'F'))".length,
    b = ('function'.length-'F'.length)*4;
alert("you should" + (a<b?"":" NOT") + " use this technique!");
```

Answer (score 4):

In the following link you'll find surprisingly good tricks to minify js code for this competition:

http://www.claudiocc.com/javascript-golfing/

One example: (extracted from section **Short-circuit operators**):

```
if (p) p=q;  // before
p=p&&q;      // after

if (!p) p=q; // before
p=p||q;      // after
```

Or the more essoteric **Canvas context hash trick**:

```
// before
a.beginPath
a.fillRect
a.lineTo
a.stroke
a.transform
a.arc                                  

// after
for(Z in a)a[Z[0]+(Z[6]||Z[2])]=a[Z];
a.ba
a.fc
a.ln
a.sr
a.to
a.ac
```

And here is another resource link with amazingly good tricks: https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques

Comment: Be careful with the Canvas Context hash trick, it's not future proof. If browsers add new methods to the Context later (as they have done since 2010), your code won't work because the current hashes won't target the same methods anymore. For example, `a.ac` now targets `arcTo()` instead of `arc()`.

Answer (score 2):

First off all, just throwing your code into a minifier won't help you that much. You need to have the extreme small file size in mind when you write the code. So in part, you need to learn all the tricks yourself.

Also, when it comes to minifiers, [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) is the new shooting star here, its output is smaller than GCC's and it's way faster too. And since it's written in pure JavaScript it should be trivial for you to find out what all the tricks are that it applies.

But in the end it all comes down to whether you can find an intelligent, small solution for something that's awsome.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware that minifiers are only part of the solution. I was hoping that someone might have some advice about "the tricks".

Answer (score 2):

Also:

Dean Edwards Packer
http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Uglify JS
http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs

Answer (score 1):

A friend wrote [jscrush](http://www.iteral.com/jscrush/) packer for js1k.

Keep in mind to keep as much code self-similar as possible.

My workflow for extreme packing is: closure (pretty print) -> hand optimizations, function similarity, other code similarity -> closure (whitespace only) -> jscrush.

This packs away about 25% of the data.

There's also [packify](https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-packify), but I haven't tested that myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only online version of [@cowboy](http://twitter.com/cowboy)'s packer script:

http://iwantaneff.in/packer/

Very handy for packing / minifying JS

Comment: Broken link :-(